# Can I export all Wordpress pages, preferences, ect?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a website built with Wordpress and it has since been hacked and will forward customers to a different website that displays inappropriate things. I do not have any backups of the website so I can not just restore a backup and get it back to normal.

So my question is do I have to re-do all my pages and everything on my website if I delete the website and all of its contents or is there a way to export all the information about the website so I can import all of my settings and avoid having to redo the entire website? Including the theme?

Answer (score 0):

If you have admin access for the site you can go to tools->export and you can create backup in the form  of xml which you can use into your another website. Usually in case of hacking/ malware attack the malicious code is added onto site's theme so you can reinstall theme and import data